# Agda stdlib List max

Tags: list, agda

I'm trying to get the max element of a `Data.List`:

```
listMax : max ℕ (2 ∷ 1 ∷ []) ≟ 2
listMax = ?
```

but don't understand why I'm getting this error:

```
Set !=< (Relation.Binary.Bundles.TotalOrder _b_20 _ℓ₁_21 _ℓ₂_22)
when checking that the expression ℕ has type
Relation.Binary.Bundles.TotalOrder _b_20 _ℓ₁_21 _ℓ₂_22
```

I'm guessing that ℕ should instead be something of type
`Relation.Binary.Bundles.TotalOrder _b_20 _ℓ₁_21 _ℓ₂_22`
but I don't know how to get something of that type and why is it needed to get the max element.

**EDIT**

Looking at the signature for `max` in `Data.List.Extrema` I see:

```
max : B → List B → B
```

and I see that B is defined here

```
open TotalOrder totalOrder renaming (Carrier to B)
```

I'm not sure why ℕ can't be a Carrier.

I also found in `Data.Fin.Properties`:

```
≤-totalOrder : ℕ → TotalOrder _ _ _
```

and tried

```
listMax : {n : ℕ} → max (≤-totalOrder n) (2 l.∷ 1 l.∷ l.[]) ≡ 2
```

but am now getting this error:

```
List _A_27 !=< Fin n
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  List _A_27
matches the expected type
  Relation.Binary.Bundles.TotalOrder.Carrier (≤-totalOrder n)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this example in `Data.String.Base`:

```
rectangle : ∀ {n} → Vec (ℕ → String → String) n →
            Vec String n → Vec String n
rectangle pads cells = Vec.zipWith (λ p c → p width c) pads cells where

  sizes = List.map length (Vec.toList cells)
  width = max 0 sizes
```

I found out that the call to `max` should look like

```
max 0 (2 l.∷ l.[])
```

and also found that I was missing the import:

```
open import Data.List.Extrema ℕₚ.≤-totalOrder
```

For a reason I don't yet know, using this import doesn't give the error:

```
ℕ != (Relation.Binary.TotalOrder _b_26 _ℓ₁_27 _ℓ₂_28)
when checking that the expression 0 has type
Relation.Binary.TotalOrder _b_26 _ℓ₁_27 _ℓ₂_28
```

that I was getting from doing this import:

```
open import Data.List.Extrema (max)
```

I'm still curious as to what makes the import

```
open import Data.List.Extrema ℕₚ.≤-totalOrder
```

work.